# Python - reading characters from tyre image opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I am having to solve the problem where I have to detect the tire dot code in a given tire image and recognize the characters in the tire.

Sample :- 
https://www.tirerack.com/images/tires/tiretech/determining_age/Post_2000_Full_Dot.jpg

I am using OPENCV to perform this task and referred the following link for reference https://github.com/schollz/python-ocr.

I have also used a Canny Edge and SWT detection to perform the task, but it has also not helped. I used the libpillowfight library for the same.

This approach is able to contrast the image but not able to extract the characters efficiently.

Can anyone suggest a better way to achieve this. Help appreciated.

Comment: so what info exactly do you want to extract from your sample image?

Comment: I've never used this OCR tool. However, I've used Tesseract, and I can tell this image is pretty hard to extract information from. I believe you would need to "dewarp" your tire (trying to create straight text lines) before running the OCR tool for better results.

Comment: Also, you could tell us the parameters you are using on each algorithm (pre-processing and OCR tool), what results have you found until now. Some minimal verifiable example would also help us to reproduce your problem...

Comment: The python-ocr git repository has two python files process_image.py and extract_text.py. I have made the process_image.py compatible with the latest opencv 3.2.0 and processed the input image and the resultant image obtained from process_image.py is given to the extract.py function which in-turn calls tesseract to optically recognise the characters in the image. So all I have done is make the process_image.py compatible with opencv 3.2.0 and then pass the image to the extract_text.py to extract the text and I have followed the readme file.  There is no additional parameters

Comment: @Anonymous did you find any solution for this how to read the text from the Tyre.